# How can I tell if this weapon is magic or not?

Tags: torchlight

In torchlight there are three passive weapon abilities "Melee", "Ranged", and "Magic".  It's pretty clear that a Broadsword is a Melee weapon is a Bow is a Ranged weapon, but how can I tell if a Quarterstaff is a Melee or Magic weapon?  What about a Scepter?

*I'm not asking for answers to these specific examples, but rather a general way to identify the "Magic" weapons.*

Answer (score 10):

Wand- and Staff-type weapons are considered "magic weapons." You can tell what type of weapon an item is by looking in the top-right corner of a tooltip:

[image]

For example, scepters are considered wands and are therefore magic weapons.

You can tell what weapon types correspond to weapon "class" by checking the descriptions of the corresponding expertise skills:

> #### Magic Weapon Expertise
>
> Mastery of Wands and Staves, and reduced requirements for Rings and Amulets.
>
> #### Martial Weapons Expertise
>
> Mastery of Swords, Axes, Maces, and Polearms
>
> #### Ranged Weapons Expertise
>
> Mastery of Bows, Pistols, Crossbows, and Rifles